# How to prove that the *smallest* rationalizing factor of $a+b\sqrt{c}$ is $a-b\sqrt{c}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been learning about surds and rationalizing. I know the identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ (which can be rewritten as $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=a-b$), so it makes sense that the method in the title *will* rationalize the expression.

Is there any way to prove that the *smallest* rationalizing factor of $a+b\sqrt{c}$ is $a-b\sqrt{c}$?

Also, what about more complicated expressions like $\sqrt[n]{a}x+\sqrt[m]{b}y$? How would you rationalize those?

Comment: just... multiply them?

Comment: It sounds to me like Exodd and Cheese Cake have mixed up the direction you're interested in: you know that $(a + b \sqrt{c})(a - b \sqrt{c})$ is rational, but I suspect you want some kind of uniqueness result, is that right? As in, if $a + b \sqrt{c}$ is multiplied by some expression of $a, b, c$, then it has to be $a - b\sqrt{c}$, or something along those lines?

Comment: There is no **the** rationalising factor. There is only **a** rationalising factor. One such factor is much more common to use than all the others combined, because it's nice, and that has led some to use "the" in error. But proving objectively that it is the nicest involves quantifying this niceness, and that's hairy.

Comment: well of course the result's gonna be rational, but a rationalizing factor has to be the *least* amount / simplest expression to multiply by without knowing anything additional about a, b, and c. (yes, @TheoBendit, I'm thinking of something along those lines!)

Comment: @avighnac It is better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @avighnac It's not hard to see that, removing the nebulous constraint of "similarity", all rationalising factors must be rational multiples of each other. If $(a + b\sqrt{c})P(a, b, c) = q \in \Bbb{Q}$, then $P(a, b, c) = q(a - b\sqrt{c})/(a^2 + b^2 c^2)$. So, all rationalising factors will essentially be $a - b\sqrt{c}$, with some rational factor included. We could write, for example, $\frac{a}{b} - \sqrt{c}$ as well, instead. Is this simpler than $a - b \sqrt{c}$? That's for you to decide. Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $x=a+b\sqrt{c}$ you can try to find its minimal polynomial:

$$(x-a)^2=b^2c\iff x^2-2ax+a^2-b^2c=0$$

Solving it with the quadratic formula gives your roots $a\pm b\sqrt{c}$ whose product (i.e $x^2-sx+p=0$) $p=a^2-b^2c$ is rational provided $a,b,c$ are.

Therefore both roots are conjugated.

You can proceed similarly with more complicated expressions in theory, but it is not guaranteed that you'll be able to find the other roots is the degree of the polynomial is too high.

e.g. it gets ugly very quickly:

For the simple $x=a^{1/2}+b^{1/3}$ the conjugated quantity is

$y=a^{5/2}-b^{1/3}a^2+a^{3/2}b^{2/3}-ab+a^{1/2}b^{4/3}-b^{5/3}$ (thanks CAS)

*Note: it is related to the factorization of $(x^n+1)$*

So there is not much hope for higher exponents.

Comment: What's a minimal polynomial, exactly?

Comment: The polynomial $p$ with rational coefficients which has the irrational number given as a root. The minimality is about its degree.

Comment: @zwim Hi, could you please order the terms of $y$ in terms of the power of $a$? Thank you! +1

Comment: @zwim I think it is more related to the factorization of $x^n\pm y^n$ - I have provided an idea in my solution about your example.

Answer (score 3):

To deal with the general question in general terms.

An algebraic number (a root of a polynomial in one variable which has integer coefficients) is always of the root a polynomial of minimal degree with integer coefficients and it is the roots of such a polynomial which are the conjugates you are looking for. [You know this exists because by definition you have a polynomial of some degree, and the polynomial you are looking for has at most that degree].

You can always reduce the polynomial by any common divisor of the coefficients, and make the leading term (coefficient of the highest power of $x$) positive, and this gives a unique "minimal polynomial" [if there were two different ones of the same degree, the division algorithm for polynomials would give a polynomial of lower degree]. Multiplying the polynomial by a non-zero constant factor does not change its roots.

If the leading term has coefficient $1$ the roots of the polynomial are called "algebraic integers".

Finding the minimal polynomial can be harder than knowing it exists. This takes us into the realms of Galois theory and field extensions.

The general theory tells us that the sum or product of any two algebraic numbers is itself algebraic, so these observations apply to the more complicated expression you exhibit - and to expressions much more complicated looking than that.

It is in general quite difficult to determine the degree of the minimal polynomial of a complicated expression. But most "real life" examples are relatively simple, and they often display exploitable symmetries [One way of thinking about Galois theory is that it involves the study of such symmetries]. Given how complicated the expressions can get, it is not surprising that deeper properties are the key to understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As the User Exodd suggested, you can just multiply them using the formula $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ by substituting.

**Part 1: Proving that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$**

We can see that

$$(a+b)(a-b)=a(a-b)+b(a-b)=a^2-ab+ba-b^2=a^2-b^2$$

**Part 2: Proving that $(a+b \sqrt{c})(a-b\sqrt{c})$ is rational for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$**

We can see that

$$(a+b \sqrt{c})(a-b\sqrt{c})=a^2-(b\sqrt{c})^2=a^2-b^2c$$

Since the identity in Part 1 is proven. Also, $a, b, c$ are rational, and so doing multiplication and subtraction between them will result in a rational number.

**Part 3:**

From Zwim's answer, using the simple example of rationalising $a^{1/2}+b^{1/3}$, there is an extremely long factor. I will multiply the two below.

\begin{align}
&\quad(a^{1/2}+b^{1/3})(a^{5/2}-a^{4/2}b^{1/3}+a^{3/2}b^{2/3}-a^{2/2}b^{3/3}+a^{1/2}b^{4/3}-b^{5/3})\\\\
&=a^{6/2}-a^{5/2}b^{1/3}+a^{4/2}b^{2/3}-a^{3/2}b^{3/3}+a^{2/2}b^{4/3}-a^{1/2}b^{5/3}\\
&\qquad\ \ \ \!+ a^{5/2}b^{1/3}-a^{4/2}b^{2/3}+a^{3/2}b^{3/3}-a^{2/2}b^{4/3}+a^{1/2}b^{5/3}-b^{6/3}\\
&=a^3-b^2
\end{align}

Here, we can clearly see that when substituting $x=a^{1/2}$ and $y=b^{1/3}$, we need to find the smallest number such that the number, when multiplied by $1/2$ and $1/3$ will result in an integer. This is $6$, and so we divide $x^6-y^6$ by $x+y$ to find a rationalising factor (although I am not sure if it is the smallest).

Note: Here, $x^6+y^6$ is not a multiple of $x+y$.

Comment: The OP has $a$ and not $\sqrt a$. Also this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Gary I have fixed this partial answer up, and it seems that the OP has edited their question, and so please expect an edit to my answer soon.

Comment: @Gary I have updated my answer.